# Sending VIdeo File on WOWZA using RTMP in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk, rtmp, wowza

I want to send a video file on wowza server using RTMP. I am able to send audio file but not able to send video file on wowza server. Can anyone tell me how can i achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can create a LIVE stream if your application is written in AdobeAIR, not sure if you can stream and existing video file. Check AdobeAIR documentation

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Android Documentation

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

[image: Android Network Multimedia Support]

You will see RTSP is supported but **not** RTMP.